# how to connect Spring boot to a Docker container with Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker

I'm trying to connect spring boot to a docker container (mongodb) directly
this is a sharding example where mongos is the query router and i'm tryng to connect to the query router.
These are the docker executions

```
docker network create --driver bridge xnet
docker run -it --rm --net=xnet -p 27016:27016 --hostname config-1 --name config-1  mongo:3.4.9 --port 27016 --replSet config --configsvr
docker exec -it config-1 mongo --port 27016 
  rs.initiate({ _id: "config", members: [{ _id : 0, host : "config-1:27016" }]});
docker run -it --rm --net=xnet -p 27015:27015 --hostname mongos --name mongos mongo:3.4.9 mongos --port 27015 --configdb config/config-1:27016
docker run -it --rm --net=xnet -p 27018:27018 --hostname shard-1 --name shard-1 mongo:3.4.9 --port 27018 --shardsvr
docker run -it --rm --net=xnet -p 27019:27019 --hostname shard-2 --name shard-2 mongo:3.4.9 --port 27019 --shardsvr
docker exec -it mongos mongo --port 27015 
    sh.addShard("shard-1:27018");
    sh.addShard("shard-2:27019");
    sh.enableSharding("test_db");
```

these are springboot confifuration

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=mongos
spring.data.mongodb.port=27015
spring.data.mongodb.database=test_db
```

Spring show me this error,it don't reach the mongos container
whats i'm doing wrong?

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: mongos
    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:211) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:75) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:180) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:152) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: mongos
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$CachedAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:797) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:883) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1368) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1302) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:203) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.0.jar:na]
    ... 6 common frames omitted

2021-12-18 11:45:58.208  INFO 23292 --- ['}-mongos:27015] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server mongos:27015
```

Comment: Why do you need `-p` and `--port`? Which command there is actually running the Spring app? Is there a specific reason not to use Docker Compose?

Comment: i would connect to the container by spring.In spring i'm using spring data mongodb,i'm not using any configuration

Comment: I understand all that. 1) Doesn't answer why you think you'll need multiple docker run commands instead of a single Docker Compose file. 2) You do understand that `-p value:value` and `--port value` do the same things? 3) You've not shown your app running in Docker, so no container hostname is going to resolve outside the Docker network you've created, which explains your error; perhaps you want to try `localhost:27015`?